# Yii Framework Error with 64 Bit server

Tags: yii, 64-bit

I have developed the site with Yii Framework. Its working fine with 32 bit server.

When i install the same code in 64 bit server, it shows the error like below:

```
PHP notice

Undefined variable: id

D:\wamp\www\mysite\protected\views\site\inner.php(46)

34                     <option value="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/aboutus">About Us</option>
35                     <option value="<?php echo $contactlink; ?>">Contact Us</option>
36                    <option value="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/fundraising">Fundraising</option>
37                     <option value="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/testimonials">Testimonials</option>
38             </select>
39             </div>
40                     <script type="text/javascript">
41 //Redirect the user to registration process
42 $("#free1").click(function() {
43 var val=1;
44       $.ajax({
45         type: 'POST',
46         url: '<?php echo CController::createUrl('site/sessionsetting') ?>?val='+val+'&id=<?php echo $id; ?>&mail=<?php echo $mailicon; ?>',
47         success: function(data){
48             //alert(data);
49             if(data == 'test1')
50             {
51                 window.location.href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/registernow";
52             }
53             if(data == 'test')
54             {
55                 window.location.href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/registernow?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&mail=<?php echo $mailicon; ?>";
56             }
57         }
58       });
```

Here, the $id is a query string used in some cases and not in other cases. I searched in google. But not got the solution. Please advise to fix the error.

Comment: It's possible the issue has nothing to do with 32 vs 64 bit, but rather with your error reporting settings. Try adding `error_reporting(0);` to the start of the script and seeing if that resolves the issue. If so, then you can add a proper check to the `echo $id` to only echo if the variable is actually set.

Comment: do a var_dump(isset($id));, if it returns false your server is fine and you should take a look at where you should set the id variable. or set error_reporting to 0 and ignore the fact that your $id isn't set.